# Converting this code snippet from VBS to Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have to convert this to Powershell:

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
sScriptPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - (Len(WScript.ScriptName) + 1))


    WshShell.run "MsiExec.exe /i " & Chr(34) & sScriptPath & "\Install.msi" & chr(34) & " Transforms=" & chr(34) & sScriptPath & "\Install.mst" & chr(34),0 , True

WScript.Quit(0)
```

What I know:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

is default in Powershell

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

is something like

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell -Strict
```

Can I then do

```
$oEnv = $WshShell.Environment("Process")
```

What WScrip.ScriptFullName is the full path or the current script?

How do I call that WshShell.run command in Powershell?

Comment: Tada: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221101.aspx

Comment: Thanks man, however the Download this conversion guide leads to an unavailable page. Can I access it other ways?

Comment: Just read it online: the table of contents is in the left pane.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you'd normally just use

```
$env:VARIABLE
```

instead of something convoluted like

```
$oEnv = (New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).Environment('Process')
$oEnv.Item('VARIABLE')
```

If you need to get a variable specifically from the "User", "Machine", or "Process" environment you'd use something like this:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('VARIABLE', 'User')
```

The equivalent to `WScript.ScriptFullName` is [`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) (or `$PSScriptRoot` in more recent versions).

Instead of the `Run` method you'd use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`).